# How to pass all events to parent in VueJS

Tags: vue.js

#### Passing Props

In **VueJS** if you set `inheritAttrs` to `false` and use `v-bind="$attrs"` you pass all props not declarated in a component to its child. Is there a similar way to pass all events coming from child to its parent in **VueJS**?

#### Code Example

**Wrapper**

```
<template>
  <child-component v-bind="$attrs" />
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  inheritAttrs: false
  ...
}
</script>
```

**Child**

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  ...
  props: {
    prop1: Boolean,
    prop2: Boolean
  }
  ...
}
</script>
```

**Parent**

```
<template>
  <wrapper :prop1="false" :prop2="true" />
  ...
</template>
```

Comment: you mean the usual events like `@click`?

Comment: Yes, but all events coming from a child, even the custom events

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To pass all events use

```
v-on="$listeners"
```

For Vue 3.x:

```
v-bind="$attrs"
```

see [listeners removed](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/listeners-removed.html)
(thanks to AverageHelper)