# How to pass all events to far ancestor component in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

The question is similar to this one, except, the emit event is not going to the grand parent, but a further one.

[How to pass all events to parent in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64610007/how-to-pass-all-events-to-parent-in-vuejs)

The way I am trying to emit all events up the stack is this way:

```html
<View_5 /> <!-- does an emit event -->

<View_4 v-on="$attrs" /> <!-- pass all events to parent -->

<View_3 v-on="$attrs" /> <!-- pass all events to parent. But it breaks here. -->
```

At View_3, it doesnt pass the events to its parents.  What I'm i doing wrong?

[EDIT] - Here is a link to a sample project [on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-trsfuh?file=src/components/DD.vue)

Click the black square, and you can see the text changes. This works because it bubbled to the a "go" event from components D -> to C -> to B -> to A, using the old fashion way.
Now how do i make it so that components C and B do **NOT** specifically look for the "go" event, but simply pass *all* events up to component A?

Comment: If it is a large app and you need to pass events to a far ancestor, isn't it time to add Vuex or Pinia to your project?

Comment: The project alreeady has vuex.  But this isnt a case where vuex can be used without making the components too tightly coupled.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'm not a big fan of emitting the events up the stack if the event is not emitted to a direct parent and should go way up, exactly for the reasons you mentioned: it may be hard to follow where exactly things break. But that's just my opinion. What I do like to do in such cases is to use [EventBus](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-event-bus-in-vue-js-to-pass-data-between-components/).

> Essentially, an event bus is a Vue.js instance that can emit events in one component, and then listen and react to the emitted event in another component directly — without the help of a parent component.

First create an `eventBus.js` file (I like to store mine in a utils directory):

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
const EventBus = new Vue()

export default EventBus
```

In your child component:

```vue
import EventBus from '@/utils/eventBus

export default {
  //rest of your setup

  methods: {
    myMethodHandler() {
      EventBus.$emit('myEvent')
    }
  }
}
```

And then in the grand parent components (the component that has to receive the event):

```vue
import EventBus from '@/utils/eventBus

export default {
  //rest of your setup

  created() {
    EventBus.$on('myEvent', () => {
      // your business logic here
    })
  }
}
```

Of course you can give the events whatever name that you like and then listen to the same event. And you can pass payload if needed - just pass it in the emitted event right after the event name and receive them in the EventBus callback function:

```js
EventBus.$emit('myEvent', someString, someObject)
//...
EventBus.$on('myEvent', (someStringPayload, someObjectPayload) => {
  // do your thing
})
```

The examples above are for Vue2. For Vue3, according to the [official doc](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/events-api.html#event-bus), you can use a third party library, such as [mitt](https://github.com/developit/mitt) or [tiny-emitter](https://github.com/scottcorgan/tiny-emitter).

Comment: this can work yes, but I wanted it solved with message passing up the stack. If i have no other way to get this done, then i'll roll with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

`v-on="$attrs"` should be `v-bind="$attrs"`.

---

`$attrs` contains key-value pairs of attributes and their values. For `@go="handler"`, `$attrs` would be `{ onGo: handler }`, where the `on`-prefix is automatically to the key.

`v-on="obj"` creates event handlers for the key-value pairs in `obj`. For instance, `v-on="{ foo: handler }` creates a listener for the `foo` event that runs `handler()`.

Given the above, `v-on="$attrs"` in your case would incorrectly create a listener for the **`onGo`** event (when it really should be for the **`go`** event). Further, each `v-on="$attr"` in the nested components would prepend `on` to the name at each nested level, leading to `onOnOnGo` in `DD.vue`.

#### Solution

Use [`v-bind="$attrs"`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-bind) to correctly forward the `v-on` directive:

```html
<!-- AA.vue -->
<BB @click="onClick" />

<!-- BB.vue -->
<CC v-bind="$attrs" />

<!-- CC.vue -->
<DD v-bind="$attrs" />

<!-- DD.vue -->
<button v-bind="$attrs" />
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-forward-attrs?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FDD.vue)